# SSH to docker container in ECS Fargate task

Tags: ssh, amazon-ecs, openssh, aws-fargate

We're implementing our Applications and databases on AWS ECS-Fargate. And I'm just wondering how can I SSH into the containers reside in the Fargate task.

The docker image is configured to accept ssh connections based on this post:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/

We have 2 containers in the ECS fargate task (PHP and MySQL), and has this IP address: 100.10.35.120

[docker containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Ry2.png)

Port 22 is opened in the "task definition", and exposed inside the dockerfile:

[task definition port 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpUSQ.png)

Security group has port 22 opened to all:

[security group port 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEea3.png)

I can ping on the IP address from my VPN network, but cannot telnet on port 22 or use ssh:

[ping is working, while telnet and ssh are not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJKLr.png)

Can anyone help me fix this issue please, we just want to have ssh access to the docker containers in the fargate task.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ali

Comment: I remember hearing no ssh access is given to containers created through fargate ... however I cannot point you to documentation saying this

Comment: There should be much more details in the question, the screenshot is lacking to show which container is this attributed to, which networking mode are you on? which subnet is it attached to? maybe it is private without an attached nat gateway, to troubleshoot the container/configuration i'd suggest maybe to first bypass some elements and assign a public ip to the task, change the definition and rerun the task once test is complete to shutdown that connectivity.. you will still need 0.0.0.0/0 inbound security rule, try to make it as generic as you can and narrow it down. or post more information

Comment: Any joy in the end?